# On an application of Bézout's theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, projective-geometry, projective-space

Let,$H$  be a hyperplane in $\mathbb{P}^{n}, n\geq 3$ and $C =Z(f_1,...,f_r)$ (where $r=n-1$) be an irreducible curve which does not contain $H$. If we have $\deg(f_i)=d_i$, for each $i$,then can we say by Bézout's Theorem that $|H \cap C| \leq d_1...d_r$? (where points are counted with multiplicity).

Can somebody give a reference of this?

Any help from anyone is welcome

Comment: It is certainly wrong as you stated it. For example if $f_1 = f_2$, then $C = Z(f_1, f_2, \dotsc, f_r) = Z(f_2, f_3, \dotsc, f_r)$, but clearly $d_1 d_2 \dotsm d_r \neq d_2 d_3 \dotsm d_r$. You will need some conditions on your $f_i$, maybe $r = n-1$?

Comment: @red_trumpet,In my case I had exactly the case $r=n-1$,But I asked the general situation.Is it true in $r=n-1$?Is there any reference of it ?(Or Is it a straightforward application of the theorem?).For simplicity we can assume $n=3$

Comment: That might be a special case, this situation is often called a (global) complete intersection. I'm not sure about the details, but maybe you have to apply Bézout's theorem inductively, each time intersecting with the hyperplane $Z(f_i)$?